# How to prove that $C = cc^T$ is not convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints, non-convex-optimization

Consider the primary optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f_0(c,C)\\ \text{subject to} & C = cc^T\end{array}$$

at [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6022813) paper. $c$ can only take discrete values, except zero. In equation $(9)$, the author wrote that the constraint is not convex. How can I prove the non-convexity of this equality constraint?

Comment: I think you should drop the discreteness requirement.  Discrete implies non-convex, unless some definitions are tweaked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $c \neq 0$ and $C=cc^T$. Then $C = (-c)(-c)^T$ and so $(C,c), (C,-c)$ are feasible. However the average $(C , 0)$ is not feasible, hence the feasible set is not convex.

Comment: thanks for answer,  does your answer hold for discrete $c$ that can't take zero value?

Comment: I do know know what convexity means in the context of discrete parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "the constraint is convex" means that if the constraint is satisfied at two points, the constraint has to be satisfied at any convex combination of those points. In particular, it must be satisfied at the midpoint of those two points. Now, this constraint is satisfied at $c=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and at $c=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, but not at the midpoint $c=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, so it isn't convex.

Comment: thanks for answer, does your answer hold for discrete $c$ that can't take zero value?

Comment: You'd need to modify it, but I suspect so. But convexity doesn't play well with discrete values, you can't have a convex constraint for a discrete problem. The continuous relaxation either will or won't be convex, I suspect it won't be convex.